# How to show the text overflow after showing two lines in the div using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing a web page. I want to show the text overflow with the help of ellipsis to the div. But I want to show the two lines of data in the div and after that I want to handle the text overflow.  I don't want to set the fix height to the div.
How to do this using css?

Comment: I've tried many times and I'm stuck in the same place you are. And there's no possible way, not with css. Try using javascript...

Comment: only with css not possible. can use jquery ?

Comment: So you want to show two lines of text, then add an elipses. You want to do this entirely with css. Is that right?

Comment: I've done it for a single line. But i want text overflow after 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, CSS3 added a `text-overflow` property. The most this can do, though, is truncate text (and show the rest on hover, but you probably want a click function).

```
element {
    text-overflow: ellipsis; // exactly what you wanted
}
```

[Examples and docs](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/).

**`text-overflow` is not in the current version of the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/).** Bummer.

I recommend doing this with [javascript](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/truncate/) or [jQuery](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/truncate/).